# Creating rules on a distribution repository in artifactory does not work

Tags: artifactory, bintray

I got a problem defining rules on a distribution repository - trying to add rules to a generic repo with a simple-layout does not work from the web interface (using artifactory OSS version 6.12.2). When i click save, the rules are not saved. I can add a maven rule - this works fine, BUT my repository is not maven, its generic - so the maven rule always fails.

The symptom I am seeing is similar to https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16076

Does anyone have some ideas how to troubleshoot this?